# Programming Bifurcation analysis

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamic-programming, biology, bifurcation

Next year I'm going to do my final project for graduation. I've been assigned to search and study some biomathematical models with bifurcation theory and numerical bifurcation analysis.

I'm thinking about use AUTO (http://indy.cs.concordia.ca/auto/) (as my professor suggested me) for this task but would like to know if there are another good/current choices I should take into account.

I'm relatively good at programming in *Mathematica*, *Matlab*, *Maxima*, *Octave*, *Python*, *Fortran*, *C++*, and *FreeFem* so programs or libraries are both welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: biomathematicals models and [bifurcation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_theory) ? is it general/theorical or do you have a particular applied (biomathematical) problem in mind ?

Comment: I'm free to choose 2 particular problems to study ( and my professor will give me the third one).I'm waiting to know the third one in order to choose the others, so at this point I have not any problem in mind, sorry ( any suggestion will be appreciated but I understand that I should ask another question about that later)

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at [PyDSTool](https://github.com/robclewley/pydstool). It is a Python package latest version of which can be easily get via `pip`. It plays nicely with IPython notebooks (simply because it uses `matplotlib` for visualization and does it pretty well for plotting time series and bifurcation diagrams). You can describe your system of ODEs in Python and it will generate C or Fortran code for it and compile it for better performance. And since it is a Python package it plays nicely with other packages from Python environment if you need to do some extra work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AUTO is a good standard choice; it's got a pretty steep learning curve though. If you do decide to use AUTO, it's definitely worthwhile to work through the tutorials. You could consider [MatCont](https://sourceforge.net/projects/matcont/), which is a bit more user friendly, and has a natural Matlab embedding (which is good if you like Matlab). Either way, it's a good idea to invest time to learn how to use (at least one of) these programs, it's a valuable skill.

Especially since you've got an affinity with programming, I would suggest you use a specialised program (such as AUTO or MatCont), instead of using general purpose mathematical software. I think that, with your skills and experience, you'll get the hang of it fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I would write everything in *Mathematica* since it has great symbol manipulation and superb flow visualization functions, such as

[image]